# How can i optimise or any other better alternative to MySQL successive sub-query.

Tags: mysql

I have 4  tables `cat_l1, cat_l2, cat_l3, data` and need to find the summary of `cat_l1` as how may `cat_l2, cat_l3` and `data` under `cat_l3`.

I am using this subquery

```
SELECT f.*, count(d.id) as data_count 
    FROM (SELECT e.*, COUNT(c.id) as cat_l3_count 
          FROM (SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.id) AS cat_l2_count FROM cat_l1 a
                LEFT OUTER JOIN cat_l2 b 
                ON a.id = b.catl1_id 
                GROUP BY (a.id))AS e 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN cat_l3 c 
          ON e.id = c.catl1_id 
          GROUP BY (e.id))as f 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN data d 
    ON f.id = d.catl1_id 
    GROUP BY (f.id)
```

I am new to MySQL and stack-overflow so sorry for any incorrect way to question this, 
My question is I am using above sub-query and getting the expected output and database is really big, is there much better approach to reach the output or sub-query is good approach.

```
id | name | cat_l2_count | cat_l3_count | data_count 
1  |   A1 |      2       |     4        |     8
2  |   B1 |      1       |     2        |     7
```

**To build schema use this:**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Apr 07, 2017 at 10:27 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.13-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.6.20

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `userdata`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cat_l1`
--

CREATE TABLE `cat_l1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cat_l1`
--

INSERT INTO `cat_l1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'A1'),
(2, 'B1');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cat_l2`
--

CREATE TABLE `cat_l2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `catl1_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cat_l2`
--

INSERT INTO `cat_l2` (`id`, `name`, `catl1_id`) VALUES
(1, 'A2', 1),
(2, 'B2', 1),
(3, 'C2', 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `cat_l3`
--

CREATE TABLE `cat_l3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `catl1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catl2_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `cat_l3`
--

INSERT INTO `cat_l3` (`id`, `name`, `catl1_id`, `catl2_id`) VALUES
(1, 'A3', 1, 1),
(2, 'B3', 1, 1),
(3, 'C3', 1, 2),
(4, 'D3', 1, 2),
(5, 'E3', 2, 3),
(6, 'F3', 2, 3);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `data`
--

CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `catl1_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catl2_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `catl3_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `data`
--

INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `name`, `catl1_id`, `catl2_id`, `catl3_id`) VALUES
(1, 'D1', 1, 1, 1),
(2, 'D2', 1, 1, 2),
(3, 'D3', 1, 1, 2),
(4, 'D4', 1, 1, 2),
(5, 'D5', 1, 2, 3),
(6, 'D6', 1, 2, 4),
(7, 'D7', 1, 2, 3),
(8, 'D8', 1, 2, 4),
(9, 'D9', 2, 3, 5),
(10, 'D10', 2, 3, 5),
(11, 'D11', 2, 3, 5),
(12, 'D12', 2, 3, 5),
(13, 'D13', 2, 3, 5),
(14, 'D14', 2, 3, 6),
(15, 'D15', 2, 3, 6);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `cat_l1`
--
ALTER TABLE `cat_l1`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `cat_l2`
--
ALTER TABLE `cat_l2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `cat_l3`
--
ALTER TABLE `cat_l3`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `data`
--
ALTER TABLE `data`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `cat_l1`
--
ALTER TABLE `cat_l1`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `cat_l2`
--
ALTER TABLE `cat_l2`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `cat_l3`
--
ALTER TABLE `cat_l3`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `data`
--
ALTER TABLE `data`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=16;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```